# DataGridView URL Hyperlinking

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am currently making a database to store previous projects as I am cleaning out my hard drive.

I am currently using a DataGrid to store all information, and I have a link section. I would like the link section to be highlighted, all the files have different URLs so I can't use an OnClick Process.Start. I have found many tutorials which I have attempted which don't work.

Here is the code below. It has 3 columns, trying to put a URL in the last.
When I click the URL in the column, I want it to load the browser up and open the website.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent()
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add
    (
        "TrustEditz",
        "GTA",
        "http://www.mediafire.com/download/e4qd1r5r4170onj/Vert.rar"
    );  
}




 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        /// This object will have the link text in it
        // It's important to note that we are casting DataGridViewCell Class to
        // sender object
        var theComponent = (DataGridViewCell)sender;
        var val = (string)theComponent.Value.ToString(); // Or theComponent.Value.ToString();

        if (val == (string)theComponent.Value.ToString())
        {



        switch (val)
        {
            case "http://www.mediafire.com/download/e4qd1r5r4170onj/Vert.rar":
                Process.Start("http://www.mediafire.com/download/e4qd1r5r4170onj/Vert.rar");
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }
      }
    }
```

And I'm still getting Unhandeled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue...

Comment: Please make sure that your code is formatted properly before submitting. This will help ensure people can help you as clearly and quickly as possible. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey buddy,  I tested the answer on my machine if it works for you after you try it please go ahead and mark it as the solution for me.  Thanks man,  hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When the link is clicked(or the cell/row) you need to bind an event to that action. So

```
void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Check that it is a valid row and it was in column #3 0 based indexing 
    if (!dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(2) || e.RowIndex == -1) 
    {
        return;
    }
    // Check if the current cell is not null and that the value is not null 
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == null) 
    { 
        return; 
    }

    // ******EDIT******
    // Before I said to cast the DataGridViewCell Object
    // This is wrong, since the sender is the DataGrid itself not the cell object
    // Below the code is using the variable e to reference the events row index
    var theRow = dataGridView1?.Rows?[e.RowIndex];
    var theCell = theRow?.Cells?[2];
    var val = theCell?.Value?.ToString();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("The cell value is not assigned");
        return;
    }

    switch(val) 
    {
       case "http://www.mediafire.com/download/e4qd1r5r4170onj/Vert.rar":
           // Do something
           break;
       default:
           break;
    }
}
```

The key thing here is that you are disassociating the click action from the specific cell contents.

Comment: what does it say?  You probably need to cast it to a string first is why.

Comment: A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type

Comment: I fixed my answer to be a string instead of an object

Comment: Unfortunately, I've got Unhandeled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue...

Comment: Don't use a cast then,  use the ToString()  instead.  Also put an if statement right after the assignment of val to ensure it holds something.

Comment: Part of the reason you are still having an issue is because the code you are using is different then the one in my answer.

Comment: So part of the problem, and this is in part my fault for making assumptions, is that you aren't checking to make sure the row's index they clicked on is non-negative positive integer. Also you need to ensure the column index they clicked on is not null and is the correct column to capture the event. I assumed, never assume anything.